# Перебор pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть много элементов pictureBox (pictureBox1,pictureBox2 ...). Нужно вставить в каждый элемент изображение из массива, как можно в цикле пройтись по всем элементам?

Answer (score 2):

Если вам надо искать контролы по окну/форме, ваш дизайн ошибочен.

Заведите в классе, ответственном за форму/окно, массив PictureBox'ов. Генерируйте их не по одному, а в цикле, добавляя на страницу и заполняя попутно массив. Дальше проблем быть не должно.

Если вы на WPF, ещё лучшим решением было бы, вероятно, перейти на MVVM и забыть о конкретных контролах навсегда.

Answer (score 0):

```
Controls.Find(ControlName,true) ?
```

или просто перебрать

```
   foreach(var pb in Controls)
   {
      if(pb is PictureBox)
      {
        ....
      }

   }
```